# Using jQuery on elements that were added to the DOM with JavaScript

Tags: jquery, socket.io

I have a rather complex issue involving interface-level jQuery. I'm loading the HTML for my page using JavaScript, and then after the page loads I use jQuery to listen for button clicks on a few classes. Basically, Sockets emits a page name and then JavaScript populates my page.

The problem is, jQuery does not respond to `click` events (or any events) on elements I have created in other functions of my JavaScript code. For example:

Sockets loads a page:

```
socket.on('loadpage', function (data) { 
    if (data.page == 'button') showButton(); 
});

function showButton() {
    $('.hook').html('<div class="container"><button class="btn"></button></div>');
}
```

And then later...

```
$(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
      console.log('click');
  }
});
```

This doesn't fire.

Answer (score 1):

use delegates for that

try

```
 $(".hook").on("click",".btn",function() {
  console.log('click');
 }
```

Comment: No way you fixed my entire app with one line.